# I can't resolve my syntax error in this bash script (version 4.1.2)

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Below is my bash script code for copying data, but I'm facing a syntax error in the `SUBSTRING` line. I'm new in bash so could not understand what's wrong with the syntax. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash



cd /var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/

     for i in $(echo */);   #..This loop shows number of directories  in a
folder to display them.....
       do

            echo /var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/$i
        done                echo""  echo "Above are the folders listed in current directory..."

sleep 2     echo""  echo "Taking Backup of above folders...."

sleep 3

    for i in $(echo /var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/*/ );

        **SUBSTRING=$(echo $i | cut -d'/' -f 7)
#        $SUBSTRING=$(echo $i cut -d'/' -f 7)**    ####...this also gives syntax error
        do
           cp -R $i /root/HostedPBX_Backup/$SUBSTRING               ##...Uncommment this line to copy files from HostePBX to HostedPBX_Backup.....

            done
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, a variable's name can only contain uppercase, lowercase, digits and underscore. In character class term, that would be:

```
[[:alnum:]_]
```

Also any user defined variable's name can not start with a digit.

In your case, you have variables defined as:

```
**SUBSTRING=....
$SUBSTRING=....
```

For the reasons stated earlier, these declarations are not right.

Answer (score 1):

This is not intented to give you a full solution, but rater giving you information about what is going wrong.

The for loops can be written with globs, no need for `echo` and command substitution. Actually the output from the `$(echo */)` will undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) if not quoted:

```
for i in *; do
  [ -e "$i" ] || continue
  ..
```

Seems like you want the basename from `i` at the second iteration. [Just use `${i##*/}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) which will remove everything op til and including the last slash:

```
substring=${i##*/}
```

The first for loop is listing all files in the current directoty? You can simply use:

```
printf "%s\n" *
```

[Uppercase variable names are reserved for environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), and shouldn't be used by applications.

The full script will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/" || exit 5
printf "/var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/%s\n" *
printf "\n"
sleep 2
printf "Taking Backup of above folders...\n"
sleep 3
for i in *; do
  [ -e "$i" ] || continue
  substring=${i##*/}
  # Copy line below:
  # cp -R -- "$i" "/root/HostedPBX_Backup/$substring"
done
```

You would properly be able to use replace the whole script with:

```
cd "/var/www/html/zong/public/HostedPBX/" || exit 5
cp -R -- * "/root/HostedPBX_Backup/"
```